# WPF ListView non integral scrolling

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls

How do I turn off the integral scrolling in a WPF ListView?  By default, scrolling a ListView jumps down so I must scroll a whole item at a time.  I would like to scroll half way, quarter way, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the property `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` of your `ListView` to False. Then the contents will scroll pixel-wise.

Comment: Does this affect the listview virtualisation? It seems to have serious effects on the performance of the listview in my case

Comment: @RobJohnson: Setting CanContentScroll to False disables virtualization (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879.aspx ).